# Слияние двух несортированных массивов в один сортированный

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Дано два массива:

```java
int[] array1 = {1, 5, 16, 9, 3, 8, 13, 19, 7};
int[] array2 = {12, 4, 11, 18, 10, 2, 16, 7, 11};
```

Нужно написать программу, которая с помощью сортировки слиянием соединит эти два массива в один отсортированный (по возрастанию чисел).

Comment: Задача странная. Ну про сортировку слиянием вы уже почитали? Информации море.

Answer (score 0):

Так думаю можно получить ответ.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array1 = {1, 5, 16, 9, 3, 8, 13, 19, 7};
    int[] array2 = {12, 4, 11, 18, 10, 2, 16, 7, 11};

    int[] result =
        IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(array1), Arrays.stream(array2)).sorted().toArray();

    Arrays.stream(result).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

Comment: Забыл дописать, без стримов и прочего. Тут что-то вроде простой задачки, на слияние и быструю сортировку.

Comment: Примеров полно поищите найдете

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм в виде кода на Си (считайте, что для Java это *псевдокод*)

```
void merge (int array1[], int length1, int array2[], int length2, int result[]) {
   int i1 = 0, i2 = 0, ir = 0;

   while (i1 < length1 && i2 < length2) {
     if (array1[i1] <= array2[i2]) {
        result[ir] = array1[i1];
        i1 = i1 + 1;
     } else {
        resuly[ir] = array2[i2];
        i2 = i2 + 1;
     }
     ir = ir + 1;
   }

   // далее выполнится только один из этих циклов
   while (i1 < length1) {
      result[ir] = array1[i1];
      i1 = i1 + 1;
      ir = ir + 1;
   }
   while (i2 < length2) {
      result[ir] = array2[i2];
      i2 = i2 + 1;
      ir = ir + 1;
   }
}
```

Не помню, можно ли в Java писать так -- `arr1[i++] = arr2[j++];`, поэтому явно прописал увеличение индексов.

Comment: спасибо, помогло